# How to get the same colors on different charts (plot_ly, ggplotly)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I am creating an R shiny dashboard and I created two charts:

```
output$plotDefPriorBar <- renderPlotly({
ggplotly(
  ggplot(data = dataDefPrior_barchart(), aes(x = TaskDate, y = DefectCount, fill = TaskPriority)) +        theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,size = rel(0.7)) ) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    xlab("Date") + ylab("Total defects")
) })
output$plotDefPrior <- renderPlotly({
plot_ly(dataInteractivePlotDefPrior(),
        values = counts,
        labels = task_priority,
        marker = list(colors = brewer.pal(12, "Set3")),
        type = 'pie',
        showlegend = TRUE) })
```

where

```
dataDefPrior <- reactive({
data() %>%
  select(-c(DefectType, TaskResolution)) %>%
  dcast(EpicName ~ TaskPriority) %>%
  arrange(EpicName) %>%
  janitor::adorn_totals(which = c("row", "col")) %>%
  arrange(desc(Total)) })

dataDefPrior_barchart <- reactive({
data() %>%
  select(TaskCreateDate,TaskPriority) %>%
  mutate(CreateDate = as.Date(TaskCreateDate)) %>%
  mutate(TaskDate = format(as.Date(CreateDate),"%Y-%m"))%>%
  select(-c(TaskCreateDate,CreateDate)) %>%
  group_by(TaskDate,TaskPriority) %>%
  summarize(DefectCount = n()) %>%
  arrange(TaskDate)  })
```

The same values (i.e. Won't Fix) on the charts have different colors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crMMS.png)

How to fix it? The color should be consistent on the charts.

Answer (score 0):

ggplot2 and plotly use different colour schemes. You should provide color mappings to both `plot_ly` and to `ggplot`, as below:

```
cols <- brewer.pal(12, "Set3")
g <- ggplot(data = dataDefPrior_barchart(), aes(x = TaskDate, y = DefectCount, fill = TaskPriority)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    xlab("Date") + ylab("Total defects") + scale_fill_manual(values=cols)

## For plotly
plot_ly(dataInteractivePlotDefPrior(),
        values = counts,
        labels = task_priority,
        marker = list(colors = cols),
        type = 'pie',
        showlegend = TRUE)
```